# On a scale from Optimist to Pessimist, what would be exactly in the middle?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

I am exploring the theoretical character differences between an optimist, pessimist and an idealist. Originally I had thought that an idealist would really sit in the middle of the other two, but now I'm second guessing myself. I am basically looking for a noun of a person that tries to make things the best they can possibly be, but also is not blind to or fearful of tackling any obstacles needed to overcome to get there, ultimately trying to achieve a balance, harmony, equilibrium etc. Would that be an idealist or something else?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like this question, but I don’t know if it is an English question or close to a philosophy question - https://philosophy.stackexchange.com or even psychology - https://psychology.stackexchange.com

Comment: "I am basically looking for a noun of a person that tries to make things the best they can possibly be" OP is looking for a word with a specific meaning, so this is definitely English-related

Comment: There is not always a middle ground for English antonyms. True/False. Pass/Fail

Comment: @k1eran: True/False has so many middle ground words.

Comment: @Joshua yes but one could argue that the underlying concepts don’t. So the “middle ground” words are kind of meaningless :-)

Comment: They forgot 'Engineer' in the image above, "The glass was specified twice as large as required."

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Perhaps this is the word you're looking for:

> The pessimist complains about the wind; the optimist expects it to change; the **realist** adjusts the sails.

{William Arthur Ward}

Collins defines **realist** thus:

> A realist is someone who recognizes and accepts the true nature of a situation and tries to deal with it in a practical way.

**EDIT**

> Many thanks to @Lawrence for [highlighting the distinction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/562708/on-a-scale-from-optimist-to-pessimist-what-would-be-exactly-in-the-middle#comment1391228_562709) between **idealist** and **realist**, which was vital for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: That's great. I am wondering though if an "idealist" could not also fit in the above example? Since wouldn't they theoretically see the issue, and want the ideal outcome and so adjust the sails as well?

Comment: From the internet: _There is a subtle yet important difference between **idealism** and **realism.** An idealist imagines what an ideal world would look like and then takes steps accordingly towards that ideal world. A realist, on the other hand, sees the world as it really is now, and considers how to improve it, one step at a time._

Comment: @FrontEnd The term *idealist* relates to intent or desire while *pessimist*, *realist* and *optimist* deal with perception or expectation. Hence *idealist* isn’t ‘between’ *pessimist* and *optimist*. It’s on a different dimension.

Comment: You’re welcome. Feel free to use the comment in your answer.

Comment: Just to be Devil’s Advocate, realist is a hugely overloaded term with a definition in the philosophy sphere. Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_realism talks about realists believing things have mind independent existence ie not just in the eye of the beholder. Its opposite is the antirealism. These seem on a yet another different dimension than pessimism/optimism.

Comment: Thematically similar enough to I think not warrant its own answer is *pragmatist* (which also has an overloaded philosophical meaning)

Comment: On a similar vein to @thehole , I thought about an *objective person* but again am doubtful if it is just right.

Comment: @k1eran: I think realist is better.  Objectivity deals with the mechanism (i.e., logic/reasoning rather than emotion) used to have a perception.  Realist deals with the perception itself, which is a better parallel for optimist and pessimist.

Comment: I think idealists also tend to be optimists, since taking steps to realize the ideal presumes that things will get better if you try.

Comment: @Barmar I could be wrong but I would think an Idealist could also be pessimistic in that they feel things are so far away from the ideal that while they may strive to make things ideal again they are ultimately frustrated with never achieving the impossible ideal they aim for.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps "pragmatist" is somewhere in the middle, neither optimistic nor pessimistic but concerned more with matters of fact than with what could or should be.

Comment: Yep, I think "pragmatist" is better than "realist." To me, "realist" implies that the individual's interpretation of reality is somehow accurate. Whereas "optimist", "pessimist", and "pragmatist" connote a degree of indifference about whether the individual's interpretation is actually accurate, and are more concerned with the manner of interpretation itself.